# Cannot convert expression type 'lambda expression' to return type bool

Tags: lambda, c#-3.0, expression, messaging

I keep getting this message when attempting to use the following in a test.

> Cannot convert expression type 'lambda expression' to return type bool

The problem occurs on the line..

// x.Send(IsObjectMessageOf(m => weLikeIt));

```
[Test]
        public void should_send_add_comment_message__when_user_adds_comment()
        {
            Event currentEvent = SampleEventBuilder.PopulatedByNextId()
                .NewState()
                .BuildDomain();

            _repository.Setup(x => x.FindByEventId(It.IsAny<int>()))
                .Returns(currentEvent);

            var eventComment = AddComment.Create(currentEvent.Key, currentEvent.Id, "comment", Time.Now, "client", Guid.NewGuid());

            _handler.Consume(eventComment);

            Func<EventComment, bool> weLikeIt = ec => ec.EventId == currentEvent.Id;


            _sender.Verify(x =>
                            {

                                x.Send(IsObjectMessageOf<EventComment>(m => weLikeIt)); // Bombs Here!
                            });
        }


        private static ObjMessage IsObjectMessageOf<T>(Func<T, bool> matcher)
        {
            return It.Is<ObjMessage>(m => m.Body is T && matcher((T)m.Body));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lambda here:

```
x.Send(IsObjectMessageOf<EventComment>(m => weLikeIt));
```

You just need to pass a Func:

```
x.Send(IsObjectMessageOf<EventComment>(weLikeIt);
```